# How to run background task which is guaranteed to be completed while the process returns in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, background-process

I want to do something like-

```
class doSomeTask{

    public static object do_method(object request){

    //Perform some operation on request

    response = doSomeOperation(request);

    //Want to do this task in background

    writeToDB(request, response);

    return response;

    }
}
```

Process should return immediately after the response is generated while the write to database operation should be done in background. 
daemon thread can do this task in background but it does not guarantee task completion. 
So if you know any other methods then let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to be sure the background task successfully completed you have to ask for that at some time. You could wrap `writeToDB(request, response);` in a `Callable` and execute it in a `FutureTask` or `ExecutorService` and invoke `future.get()` to provoke a `ExecutionException`

Comment: Could you please explain me how to do the same

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    private static FutureTask<Void> future;

    public static Object do_method(Object request) {
        // Perform some operation on request
        Object response = doSomeOperation(request);

        // Want to do this task in background

        future = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception 
            {
                writeToDB(request, response);
                return null;
            }
        });

        // Start background thread and execute Callable (FutureTask is also a runnable)
        new Thread(future).start();

        return response;

    }

    public static Object doSomeOperation(Object request) {
        return new Object();
    }

    public static void writeToDB(Object request, Object response) throws Exception    {
        throw new Exception(); // Simulation failure on SQL insert
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object request = new Object();

        Object response = do_method(request);
        // ... do some crazy stuff with response

        try {
            future.get(); // Wait for succesfull execution of background thread
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Catch ExecutionException if any uncaught Exception in the background thread is thrown
        }
    }
}
```